# When exactly do three vectors form a right-handed triad?

Tags: vectors

My book gives two contrasting approaches to solving the same type of problems.

**Problem 1**

> If the vectors $\vec{c}$, $\vec{a}=xi+yj+zk$, and $\vec{b}=j$ are such that $\vec{a}$, $\vec{c}$, and $\vec{b}$ form a right-handed system, find $\vec{c}$. (Subjective type)

**Book approach:** they've assumed $\vec{c}=\vec{b}\times\vec{a}$ and solved for $\vec{c}$.

**Problem 2**

> What is the condition for $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ to form a right-handed system? (Fill in the blanks type)

**Book approach:** Put $[\vec{a}\text{ }\vec{b}\text{ }\vec{c}]>0$

---

As you can see, there's no relation between the two approaches. I personally am favoring the second method because its result follows from the definition of the scalar triple product itself (*volume of parallelopiped of vectors taken in order...*).

**My question:** Which approach is correct?

Comment: Both are correct, while both are different questions. Second one asks for condition for which the three can represent triad.

Comment: @samjoe Since it asks for a "condition", don't you think there can be more than one vectors like $\vec{c}$ which  satisfy the system being right-handed?

Comment: Yes you are right. btw theres a typo in second yellow box.

Comment: @samjoe Oh fixed thanks!